# How do I map CDN HTTP links to HTTPS?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

The problem:

I've done a graph search and stored http links to various pictures for a slideshow app. The problem is that now I need secure https links. Searches online will say to just re-do the request in the graph API using return_ssl_resources=1 in the request.

Long story short is that this is not possible, as the data is already stored, and those users are no longer authenticated (there's not permission to re-request).

Is there a way in FQL / Graph API to get the valid https:// link from an http:// photo link without passing through user permissions (since we already have access to the photo and just need it returned securely)?

Comment: Can you give an example link?

Comment: Someone suggest here http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/a/15426389/1427878 that just replacing the domain part of the URL from `http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net` to `https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net` would do the trick – but how reliable that is … you have to give it a try, I guess.